# How to save json values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have json values which i have tried to store inside the pandas dataframe but i am not been able to save the proper values this is my json data

```
[[{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_name': 'RAVAL,JA', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'JA Raval', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Raval', 'dob': '1988-09-22', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Jeet Raval', 'mobile_name': 'Raval', 'object_id': '277914', 'player_id': '51094', 'player_primary_role': 'opening batsman', 'player_style_id': '1', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Raval', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '397349', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '245', 'age_years': '26', 'alpha_name': 'LATHAM,TWM', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'pace bowler', 'bowling_style': 'rm', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm medium ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'TWM Latham', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Latham', 'dob': '1992-04-02', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Tom Latham', 'mobile_name': 'Latham', 'object_id': '388802', 'player_id': '59148', 'player_primary_role': 'wicketkeeper batsman', 'player_style_id': '7', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Latham', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '1099471', 'status_id': '3'}]]
```

when I am trying to store in the dataframe i am getting like this

```
0{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_n...}   
1   {'age_days': '196', 'age_years': '23', 'alpha_...} 
2   {'age_days': '99', 'age_years': '29', 'alpha_n...}
```

i need to save the data in the individual column

this is the code

```
team_1_players = pd.DataFrame(team_1_players)
print(team_1_players)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
data = [[{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_name': 'RAVAL,JA', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'JA Raval', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Raval', 'dob': '1988-09-22', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Jeet Raval', 'mobile_name': 'Raval', 'object_id': '277914', 'player_id': '51094', 'player_primary_role': 'opening batsman', 'player_style_id': '1', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Raval', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '397349', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '245', 'age_years': '26', 'alpha_name': 'LATHAM,TWM', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'pace bowler', 'bowling_style': 'rm', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm medium ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'TWM Latham', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Latham', 'dob': '1992-04-02', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Tom Latham', 'mobile_name': 'Latham', 'object_id': '388802', 'player_id': '59148', 'player_primary_role': 'wicketkeeper batsman', 'player_style_id': '7', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Latham', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '1099471', 'status_id': '3'}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

print(df)

 age_days age_years  alpha_name       batting_hand batting_style  \
0       72        30    RAVAL,JA  left-hand batsman           lhb   
1      245        26  LATHAM,TWM  left-hand batsman           lhb   

  batting_style_long      bowling_hand bowling_pacespin bowling_style  \
0      left-hand bat  right-arm bowler      spin bowler            lb   
1      left-hand bat  right-arm bowler      pace bowler            rm   

  bowling_style_long    ...    object_id player_id   player_primary_role  \
0          legbreak     ...       277914     51094       opening batsman   
1  right-arm medium     ...       388802     59148  wicketkeeper batsman   

  player_style_id player_type player_type_name popular_name portrait_alt_id  \
0               1           1           player        Raval               1   
1               7           1           player       Latham               1   

  portrait_object_id status_id  
0             397349         3  
1            1099471         3  

[2 rows x 28 columns]
```

Comment: klaus i need to ask one thing

Comment: i have more than one json rows like this how i can make it in more efficient manner you made this for only one json row

Comment: simply loop,.o is the index for which i have done, you add for others (assuming thats how your json is)

Comment: that would make one dataframe on different dataframes?

Comment: thats where concat will come in.. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html